# String between program faults

Tags: c, string, function, char, return

I'm having a bit of an issue with my program. The way it works is that a function is supposed to return a string of char's between two char's that I choose, for example "a1234a" and I want to return all characters between the 'a', I'd get 1234. The problem is that my output also prints the first 'a', so I get "a1234" instead. The code is as following:

```
char* string_between(char *s, char c){
    int length = strlen(s);
    int counter = 0;
    char* strBetween = malloc(strlen(s));

    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
      if(s[i] == c){
        counter++;
      }
      if(counter == 1){
        strBetween[i] = s[i];
      }
    }
    if(counter<2){
      free(strBetween);
      return NULL;
    }
    return strBetween;
}
```

I've tried adding `s[i] != c` in the `if(counter == 1)` statement, but then it gets worse and doesn't print anything at all. I'm still pretty new to C so please explain as simple as possible :) Thanks for reading!

Comment: Please learn how to use a debugger. With a debugger you can step through your code line by line and see what it does, all while being able to monitor variables and their values. It is an essential skill needed by all programmers.

Comment: One basic mistake: failure to terminate the returned string. Also, you can't define a function whose name starts with `str`, that's a reserved namespace.

Comment: Think about what value `i` has at the line `strBetween[i] = s[i];`.  Also, what would happen if `c` is *not* the first character in the input string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with this implementation.

First, `char* strBetween = malloc(strlen(s));` does not allocate memory for the null-terminating character, assuming your goal here is to allocate enough space to hold a string with length equal to that of the input string. Second, if you reason through the for loop, you'll see what it actually does is copy the character `c` plus the string of interest (e.g. "a1234") into the string you allocated beginning at the index it was found in the input string.

In the case of "a1234a" as the input string, it will copy over "a1234_" (with the final character being undefined). However, suppose the input string were "ggga1234aggg". The output would be the string "___a1234____" with the "_" characters being undefined. The reason adding `s[i] != c` in the `if` condition doesn't work is that you're still not addressing the undefined character(s) at the beginning of the string. In that case, you still end up with "_1234-" (using - instead of _ to avoid italicization). Most likely, the undefined characters will be `0` (i.e. null-terminator), in which case it is essentially a string of length zero, which explains your result. But of course, you should not be relying on undefined behavior regardless.

Answer (score 1):

If you pretend to be the computer and execute the body of your loop, assuming you're at the target character, it should be quite obvious why it happens. You check for `c`, increase the counter, then check if the counter is 1 in the same iteration. Obviously you're going to copy the first instance of `c`.

Swap the order of the comparisons, or use `else if` for the second one.

Also add code to properly terminate the returned string.